# How do I know which thread file belongs to boost?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, makefile

I know nothing of C++ or threads, I'm just trying to build a library which has a python wrapper for astrodynamics.

https://github.com/esa/pagmo

When I try to make the program, it keeps telling me I don't have the correct link to BOOST.

The CCMAKE finds

```
BOOST_THREAD_LIBRARY            */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
```

However, I think there might be a version mismatch. Is there any way to figure out what version a make file is expecting?

Comment: What makes you think there would be any kind of mismatch?

Comment: Please copy and paste the entire error message verbatim (or the first two dozen lines if it's very long). Guesswork is £250/hr extra, thank you.

Comment: FWIW, `libpthread` has nothing to do with Boost, it's just the standard [pthread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) library

Comment: According to the `CMakeLists.txt`, you need Boost1.48 or newer - so ensure it's installed.

Comment: On Linux, Boost threads depends on pthreads.